# How to get distinct records from a list

Tags: list, hashset

I have a list of type `Myclass`

```
List<Myclass> liSubjectIdDetail = new List<Myclass>();
```

where Myclass looks like

```
public class  Myclass 
{
    public Nullable<decimal> SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
}
```

I am adding records into liSubjectIdDetail from a table

```
foreach (decimal Id in VarCEMSIdDetail)
{
    liSubjectIdDetail.AddRange(db.Stt.MyTable.Where(x => x.Id == Id).Select(x => new Myclass { SubjectId = x.SubjectId, SubjectName = x.SubjectName }).ToList());
}
```

where Id contains a list of certain Ids on the basis of which records I fetch.

Now I want to get only distinct records in this list.

I have tried it with **hashtable** in place of **List**
and I also tried

```
liSubjectIdDetail= liSubjectIdDetail.Distinct().ToList();
```

but this too, is not working. Please give me a better solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this extension method

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
                (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        var seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
        foreach (TSource element in source)
        {
            if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
liSubjectIdDetail= liSubjectIdDetail.DistinctBy(s => s.SubjectName).ToList();
```

Comment: i am new in programming can you please tell me where i have to use the above extension

Comment: create a class file as above (i added the class def) and try the usage.